# MVVM Light- Switching Views (UserControls) in Content Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i know this Question has been around Pretty often but i want to understand this and not just to copy code. I have two UserControls and a MainWindow. What i want to achieve is simple Navigation stuff: press button 1 -> open UserControl1 in Content Control. same for button 2 with UserControl2.

This is what i got (not much but all coded by myself so excuse me if something is wrong):

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="gf_mvvmlight.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"

    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gf_mvvmlight"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"         
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" >

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Button>switch to Page 2</Button>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Page1View, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
</Grid>
```

**Page1.xaml (Page2 is the same):**

```
<UserControl x:Class="gf_mvvmlight.View.Page1View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gf_mvvmlight.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
                      DataContext="{Binding Path=Page1ViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid>
    <Label>orkpwefkwe99</Label>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModelLocater.cs:**

```
public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Page1ViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Page2ViewModel>();
    }
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public Page1ViewModel Page1View
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Page1ViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public Page2ViewModel Page2View
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Page2ViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

so my Question is: how can i make the ContentControl dynamic and open Page2View when i press the button? i dont except any code just some tips please:)

and the program should be able to switch views from every class !!!

thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I've never seen any compelling reason to use the view model locator. I usually delete it, declare an instance of MainViewModel in the App.xaml and reference it in MainWindow with `DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}"`.

Irrespective of whether you use ViewModelLocator or not, you can just use DataTemplates to populate the view. So in the MainViewModel I typically do something like this:

```
private BasePage _CurrentPage;
public BasePage CurrentPage
{
    get { return this._CurrentPage; }
    set
    {
        if (this._CurrentPage != value)
        {
            this._CurrentPage = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentPage);
        }
    }
}
```

And I subclass BasePage to my different page types i.e. PageViewModel1, PageViewModel2 etc. Then back in the xaml my MainWindow looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PageViewModel1}">
        <views:PageView1 />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PageViewModel2}">
        <views:PageView2 />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
```

...where PageView1 and PageView2 are your user controls. So now whenever you set CurrentPage to one your pages the ContentControl will populate it with the appropriate DataTemplate.

Note that just because I don't use ViewModelLocator doesn't mean I don't believe in using dependency injection, quite the opposite in fact. I just don't think it's needed here, and there are better implementations than ViewModelLocator (i.e. Ninject).

UPDATE: Clarifying this further, based on your question below...my example above implies there are 3 view models: MainViewModel, PageViewModel1 and PageViewModel2. That XAML I posted with the DataTemplates is what should be on your MainWindow, which has its DataContext set to an instance of MainViewModel. Let's say the MainViewModel constructor does something like this:

```
public MainViewModel()
{    
    this.CurrentPage = new PageViewModel1();
}
```

That line of code sets CurrentPage, and if you've declared it like I did (i.e. with property change notification) then the ContentControl in MainView will automatically be populated with an instance of the PageView1 control. It will do this because 1) the ContentControl is binding to the `CurrentPage` property, and 2) I've set up a DataTemplate that effectively says "whenever the content of something is of type PageViewModel1 I want you to display it with a PageView1 user control. Furthermore....and this is important....that PageView1 control will have its DataContext set to whatever CurrentPage is (i.e. the instance of PageViewModel1), so it can bind to properties there. So for every view we're displaying on-screen there's a corresponding view model with all the logic associated for that view.

Now let's say we refactor PageViewModel1 and PageViewModel2 to accept a pointer to the parent MainViewModel, and let's say that in response to a button press or something it does this:

```
this.MyParentMainViewModel.CurrentPage = new PageViewModel2()
```

The property has now changed, and the framework will respond by disposing of the PageView1 control and replacing it with a PageView2 control, which again has its DataContext set to CurrentPage. You've therefore "changed pages", but you've done it entirely in your view model layer and relied on data binding and data templating to propagate those changes through to the view layer automatically.

This is obviously a very, very simple example which I'm using just to illustrate how DataTemplating works. In reality child view models would never access their parent directly or indeed ever know about them, you'd usually use a dependency injection framework to pass interfaces into the children which are then handled by the parent....but that's a topic for another essay. :)

Comment: hey Mark, thanks for your answer! before my solution i had another one like yours but i couldnt swith usercontrols from an usercontrol, only from MainWindow. how would you switch the current page?

Comment: Answer clarified.